# How to display values in a multidimensional JSON array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, multidimensional-array

I'm getting a json multidimensional array (as "data" in the success function of an $.ajax call) from a php/mysql database query. The PHP script sends it to the javascript file like so:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The query can return one or more records from the database.

console.log(data) seems to only give me the first "child" array in the "parent" array. Here's what is in the console:

```
[{id:114, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Aitkin,…},...]
    0: {id:114, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Aitkin,…}
    1: {id:115, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Benton,…}
    2: {id:116, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Carlton,…}
    3: {id:117, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Chisago,…}
    4: {id:118, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Cook,…}
    5: {id:119, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Crow Wing,…}
    6: {id:120, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Isanti,…}
    7: {id:121, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Itasca,…}
    8: {id:122, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Kanabec, branchZipCodesCovered:56358, 55051}
    9: {id:123, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Lake,…}
    10: {id:124, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Mille Lacs,…}
    11: {id:125, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Pine,…}
    12: {id:126, branchStateCovered:MN, branchCountyCovered:Saint Louis,…}
    13: {id:127, branchStateCovered:WI, branchCountyCovered:Douglas,…}
```

In a different $.ajax call I'm accessing what is always a single-dimensional array with

```
$('label#branchName').text(data['name']);
$('label#branchAddress').text(data['address']);
etc...
```

But in this case I need to iterate through each of the arrays and display each of its values in a similar manner as above.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959943/how-to-access-values-in-a-multidimensional-json-array-with-jquery), but it looks like the post author is creating the array in such a way as he knows each "child" array's "name" (producers). Maybe the answer for me is in that post and I'm just not seeing it.

How can I take the outputted multidimensional array and cycle through it to display each of the array's arrays into a table - or whatever I want to do with it on the HTML side?

Comment: Seeing the actual JSON returned by the server would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: @Anthony: The code in my OP starting with "Object {..." is what I'm getting in the console. If there's a way to get more, I don't know it. How do I do that?

Comment: Your browser's developer tools or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) if you're using Firefox, all accessed by pressing the F12 key, will allow you to view AJAX requests and their responses.

Comment: Okay I found I was doing one thing wrong: The reset function in the PHP echo line was just giving me the first element in the multi-array. Removing that gave me a full array. Changing my OP appropriately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `success` callback of your `$.ajax()` call, `data` is the array, so you can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through it:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    // use individual element (an object) here, i.e. element.id to get the id
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! $.each(data, function(index,element) {
 console.log(element['branchStateCovered']);
}); is what I used to get one of the "sub" array's values. Thanks, Anthony