# Accessing multidimensional array from json with jquery

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Ok, I'm sure this is simple but I'm not jquery expert.  I have an ajax call that has an array returned as a variable.  I'm having trouble accessing that array.

Here is what I want to do.

My array is setup so that the key matches the id of an input on my page.  I want to traverse through my inputs and if there is a key that matches the id of the input, set the value of that input to the value of what's in the array.  So here is what I have so far:

```
function populateFields(table_name, user_id, div){
    $.ajax({
        data:{
            mode:'getInfo',
            table_name: table_name,
            user_id: user_id                            
        },
        url:'my_page.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        success:function(data){
            data=$.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.error != undefined){
                if(data.error !== false){
                    showError(data.error);
                } else {
                    var inputName="";

                    $('#'+div+' > input').each(function(){
                        inputName=$(this).attr('id');
                        /*Check to see if inputName is a key and if so, set the value of this input to the value matching the key*/
                    });
                }
            } else {
                showError('The script was not called properly, because data.error is undefined.');
            }
        },
        complete:function(){

        }
    });
}
```

The name of the variable being returned is called info.  So data.info is the object with the information.

In the debugger data.info has this setup:

```
Object
2: Object
  agreed:"no"
  city: null
  email: "email@email.com"
```

Any idea what the code would be between the /* */ marks?

Comment: We would need to see what your JSON looks like before commenting further.

Comment: `data=$.parseJSON(data)` get rid of that, `dataType:"text"` change that to `dataType:"json"` no reason for the other stuff.

Comment: show your actual JSON data as a sample

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959943/how-to-access-values-in-a-multidimensional-json-array-with-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: there are some caveats to using Object.hasOwnProperty() 
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/136411/940754

Not sure why your data.info variable is coming back with the '2' key, but try:

```
// check to see if input name is a key
if(data.info[2].hasOwnProperty(inputName)) {

    // set the value
    $(this).value = data.info[2][inputName];
}
```

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help.  This was it.  I couldn't figure out why the data.info[2] is the array but I think it has something to do with how I'm passing it from my ajax page.  Here is the code: `$info = $db->select('*', $_POST['table_name'], $where);` then I'm passing it back with ` echo json_encode( array( "error" => $error, "info" => $info) );` I think perhaps because I didn't turn $info into an array before passing it back?